# What's the most efficient way to use large data from Excel in my C# code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I ran a computer simulation for my Pendulum, to measure time taken to reach the lowest point, for every velocity and every angle.

As you can imagine there is a lot of data, thousands of lines for all angles and velocity.

On every frame, I will be measuring the velocity and angle of the pendulum, and will look for the closest data in my Excel spreadsheet.

How can I go about this to make sure it's not too CPU-intensive?

Should I create a massive array where every element corresponds to a certain angle: for example, myArray[30] will be for all velocities and times for all my data between 30.0 degrees and 30.999. (That way it will be avoid lots of if statements)

Or should I keep everything in my Excel spreadsheet? 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not just load all data into memory?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in my opinion would be dividing your data into intervals based on distribution since you have to access that data in every frame. Then when you measure the velocity and angle you can go look for the interval and access only that part of your data.

I would find maximum and minimum of your data points while importing to Unity and then divide that part based on `(maximum - minimum) / NumOfIntervals`. Lets say your interval size is 5 for each Angle. When you got an angle of 17 you can do  `(int)15/5 = 3`(Assuming indexes start from zero) and go for third item in your structure. This can be a dictionary or Array of an Arbitrary class instances based on your data.

I can try to help further if you can share the structure of your data. But in my opinion evenly distribution of data to every interval is important.